# How to replicate records based on weight and one attribute variable in SAS

Tags: sas

I have a SAS dataset with frequency weight. In the dataset, we also have a group variable used for the scenario differentiator. For group 1, I would like to replicate my records weight 1 time, 2 times for observations in group 2, and so on and so forth. Is there an easy way to do this in SAS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not certain if this is what you are asking for. Providing a simple worked example (with sample data) might make the question clearer.

That said, if you are looking to duplicate a record based on an integer value in one of the variables (`group` below) you can do so with a `do` [loop](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000201276.htm) and explicit `output` [statement](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000194540.htm).

```
/* Some dmmy data */
data inData;
    do group = 1 to 5;
        weight = ranuni(0);
        output;
    end;
run;

/* Output each observation group times */
data outData (drop = _i);
    set inData;
    do _i = 1 to group;
        output;
    end;
run;
```